# Show the uniform continuity of $\frac{1}{1+x^4}$ per Lipschitz-continuity or $\varepsilon - \delta$-proof

Tags: analysis, functions, continuity, epsilon-delta, lipschitz-functions

To show: the uniform continuity of $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto \frac{1}{1+x^4}$ per Lipschitz-continuity or $\varepsilon - \delta$-proof.

What I tried:

Let $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ with $|x-y| \lt \delta$, it follows:

$|f(x)-f(y)| \lt \varepsilon \Leftrightarrow |\frac{1}{1+x^4} - \frac{1}{1+y^4}| \lt \varepsilon$. I then tried to reaarrange the term so that I would see the fitting $\delta$ or the needed estimation for the Lipschitz-continuity, but it didn't work out.

Can someone help at this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could take two derivatives to find the inflection point, then plug that into the derivative to find the max derivative. That will give you uniform continuity by the mean value theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $|x|^{3} \leq 1+x^{4}$. This is because $|x| \leq 1$ implies $|x|^{3} \leq 1 \leq 1+x^{4}$ and $|x| >1$ implies $|x|^{3} \leq x^{4} \leq 1+x^{4}$.

Hence $|f'(x)|=|\frac {-4x^{3}} {(1+x^{4})^{2}}|\leq 4$. By MVT we get $|f(x)-f(y) | \leq 4|x-y|$ for all $x,y$.